# Empty Trash Hook

Tags: macos, script, trash

1. Is there a way to trigger some custom code to run if somebody tries to empty the trash like for login / logout hooks?
2. Is there a way to interrupt the empty trash process for non-admin users?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve here, do you want to prevent users from emptying the trash?

Comment: Also, can you please advise what version of macOS you're running?

Comment: I am trying to prevent standard users from emptying the trash.  I am already aware that there are consequences when the drive fills up.  The second thing I was thinking of is being able to run some code to make a copy of the trash bin prior to emptying so a backup is in place before emptying it so that it does not fill up the drive.  All computers are running OS X 10.10 - 10.12.